# Remove Card shadow from bottom in compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, card

Is there anything by which i can remove shadow from bottom of Card.

```
` Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .shadow(elevation = 0.dp, spotColor = Color.Transparent, shape = shape),
        elevation = 16.dp,
            shape = shape,
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface
        )`
```

I kept elevation as 16.dp, due to which i got shadow around card. i dont want to set shadow in bottom. is there any option to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can clip the Composable with `Modifier.clip(shape)` as following:

```
            Card(
                modifier = modifier
                    .clip(shape = shape)
                    .shadow(elevation = 0.dp, spotColor = Color.Transparent, shape = shape),
                elevation = 16.dp,
                shape = shape,
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface
            )
```

This works whenever you set shadow manually, without the elevation on card, as you set the boundaries for the following `Modifier` - meaning you put the clip modifier before any other, in our case the shadow `Modifier`.